# Multiple primeng table in ngFor with selectall checkbox

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to create dynamic multiple tables using primeng table and ngFor like below

```
<div *ngFor="...">
    <p-table>
        ...
        //header
        <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
        ...

        //body
        <p-tableCheckbox></p-tableCheckbox>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

Consider we have two tables, generated dynamically; using the data we provided in [value], with two tableHeaderCheckboxes

when we select first tableHeaderCheckbox, first table's tableCheckbox/row checkboxes has to get selected.

when we select second tableHeaderCheckbox, second table's tableCheckbox/row checkboxes has to get selected

like for third, fourth tables appropriately.

Please, help me how to achieve this.

Comment: ngFor support passing index as well. can't you achieve that via using the table index?

Comment: @AakashGarg - do you mean this - <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">

Comment: no, index in ngFor you have on div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a separate component and then placed the table code in that component, so now as expected selectall checkbox is working now.

```html
    <p-table>
        ...
        //header
        <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
        ...

        //body
        <p-tableCheckbox></p-tableCheckbox>
    </p-table>
```